# Add a recipient to email notifications based on a field's value

Tags: cognito-forms

We want a form's email notifications to be sent to different recipients depending on fields' values. We could use calculations to constitute the list of recipients but we would need to be able to use a field's name in the "To" list (which is not the case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are considering adding support for multiple conditional notifications.  This is on our Idea Board: https://trello.com/c/iXlwst3H

This would allow you to set up multiple notifications and conditionally control which to send based on information on the form.  We will likely go this route versus using calculations to determine the email address, as it will make more sense to the majority of our users.

Comment: We just released support for adding multiple email notifications and confirmations, which can be conditionally sent based on form field data.  You can also now trigger emails based on changes made while managing submitted entries!